# Python: Calculating the averages of values in a text file

Tags: python, file

When I run my code below I get a: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.977759164126'` but i dont know why

```
file_open = open("A1_B1_1000.txt", "r")
file_write = open ("average.txt", "w")

line = file_open.readlines()
list_of_lines = []
length = len(list_of_lines[0])
total = 0


for i in line:
    values = i.split('\t')
    list_of_lines.append(values)

count = 0
for j in list_of_lines:
    count +=1

for k in range(0,count):
    print k
    list_of_lines[k].remove('\n')



for o in range(0,count):
    for p in range(0,length):
        print list_of_lines[p][o]
        number = int(list_of_lines[p][o])    
        total + number
    average = total/count
    print average
```

My text file looks like:

> 0.977759164126    0.977759164126  0.977759164126  0.977759164126  0.977759164126
>   0.981717034466    0.981717034466  0.981717034466  0.981717034466  0.98171703446

The data series is in rows and the values are tab delimited in the text file. All the rows in the file are the same length.

The aim of the script is to calculate the average of each column and write the output to a text file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`int()` is used for integers (numbers like 7, 12, 7965, 0, -21233). you probably need `float()`

Comment: D'oh such a simple answer. My bad

Comment: Haha it wouldn't let me I had to wait 8 mins :(

Answer (score 0):

Python is limited on handling floating points. These all work fine here but for longer ones as well as arithmetic you are going to want to use the Decimal module.

```
import Decimal
result = Decimal.Decimal(1)/Decimal.Decimal(5)
print result
```

Link to the documentation
http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Try typing in 1.1 into IDLE and see what your result is.